# Fibonacci Sequence - using While True

Tags: python, python-2.7

I've been trying for a while to solve this Fibonacci question and to write it correctly but I always getting not the right results and its stuck at the first If in the code.

Code Below:

```
def main():
    num = 1
    num2 = 1
    num3 = 2
    Katan = True

    while Katan == True:
        if (num3 == 2):
            print num,num2,num3
            num3 = num2 + num3
            num2 = num3
        elif num3 < 10000:
            num3 = num + num2
            num2 = num
            print num,num2,num3
            num = num2
        else:
            Katan = False

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: So what is the question?

Comment: If you're getting an exception, please include the full traceback in your question. If you're getting incorrect results, please describe the results you're getting and what you expected to get instead (and why).

Comment: `its stuck at the first If in the code` no it is not

Comment: Please correct your indentation. Python is very sensible at this.

Comment: @Lazykiddy I've written that its stuck at the first if and not continue from there

Comment: @glibdud always the same like this 1,1,2 1,2,4 until infinity

Comment: @Dominique May you say where?

Comment: Your algorithm is not correct. I'd read up on the Fibonacci sequence first.

Answer (score 4):

This can be done simpler than what you are trying with something like this:

```
def main():
    # You don't need to store 3 numbers, 2 is enough
    num1 = 1
    num2 = 1

    # You don't need a variable for the while condition, ...
    while True:
        print num1

        if num2 > 10000:
            break # ... you can just break it when some condition is met

        # You can "switch" variables like this
        num1, num2 = num2, num2 + num1

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

You can make it even simpler by using [a generator](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators).

Answer (score 1):

You've been shown a better Fibonacci function, but for learning purposes here's why yours isn't working.

Let's look at your `while` loop. The first time through, you'll go through the `if` block. This sets `num3` to `3`, and then sets `num2` to `3` as well. So your variables are `(num, num2, num3) == (1, 3, 3)`.

The next iteration will then take you into the `elif` block. I've removed the `print` for clarity.

```
elif num3 < 10000:
    num3 = num + num2
    num2 = num
    num = num2
```

As you can see, after the first time you hit `num2 = num`, you are no longer *ever* changing the value of either `num` or `num2`. You just keep setting them equal to each other. As such, `num3` will never change again after the first time through either, since it depends only on `num` and `num2`. It looks to me like what you actually meant to do was set `num = num3` in that last line, using `num3` as sort of a temp variable for holding a value while swapping the others. Making that simple change makes the code *almost* do what you're trying to do, only it turns out your `if` block isn't actually necessary at all. There's nothing special about the `num3 == 2` case, and that's actually throwing off your results. So get rid of the `if` block and promote the `elif` to `if`, and your program will do more or less what you expect:

```
while Katan == True:
    if num3 < 10000:
        num3 = num + num2
        num2 = num
        print num,num2,num3
        num = num3
    else:
        Katan = False
```

There's still some trouble with the beginning of the sequence, but depending on where you're actually taking your final values from, that may be fixable by just changing your initial variables to `(num, num2, num3) == (0, 1, 1)`.